# Entity Framework modeling with .NET4, Data Annotations issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, data-annotations

I am trying to use Entity Framework on my web site. I followed tutorials and Visual Studio (2010) does not complain. However, when I add a ForeignKey data annotation, I get an error when I run on the web site that the Namespace does not exist.
`CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ForeignKey' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

After doing some searching, it appears that the ForeignKey data annotation does not exist in .NET 4.

If that is the case, is there a way to add at foreign key to the model in .NET 4?

Comment: Use your database context class to define the relationships. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ManyToMany

Comment: @aritra So your saying that i cannot do it with data annotations, i have to use Fluent API?

Comment: I suggested you a way out. Incase, if you cant use Annotations then whats wrong in using Fluent APIs, if it meets your purpose? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema is part of .NET 4.5.

Have you instead looked at the Fluent API?

Here's a video for VS 2010 specifically. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/gg194009.aspx