# CS0246 C# The type or namespace name 'ForeignKeyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, android, entity-framework, azure, code-first

I am learning using Entity Framework **Code First** to create my database
via **Azure** Mobile App Service

But I got an error , it looks like

[image]

```
CS0246 C# The type or namespace name 'ForeignKeyAttribute' 
could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And I've already used **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;**
but it seems not to work .

How can I solve this ?

=====================================================

**Finally , I solved it referring to this  !!
[Why can't I reference System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174420/why-cant-i-reference-system-componentmodel-dataannotations)**

Comment: Which version of ef are you targeting?

Comment: EntityFramework.dll , Runtime version v4.0.30319 :"(

Comment: Hmm, what version of .NET? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705040/entity-framework-modeling-with-net4-data-annotations-issue

Comment: My entity framework is 6.0 . How to see the version of .Net to a current using project ? Actually I can use Data Annotation in other project , just don't know why it doesn't work in Azure connection project. :"(

Comment: <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: Did you try changing your using statement to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations instead of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Comment: yes , finally .. I recreated the .Net project to the lasted version then it solved ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations is the namespace for ForeignKey as well as Required.

System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema is more specific. For example, if you want to map a field to a specific column name or an entity to a table name.